# My target is to return a result set where for every year (from Date) it will return the count of Meeting and NonMeeting

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table with following schema

```
Id          int (PK)
Date        datetime
IsMeeting   bit
```

My target is to return a result set where for every year (from Date) it will return the count of Meeting and NonMeeting.
Meeting are those having IsMeeting is 1.
NonMeeting are those having IsMeeting is 0 or null.

I tried writing the sql like this -

```
select year(Date) as Year,
count(year(Date)) as Total,
(select count(*) from booking where IsMeeting=1 and ID={0}) as Meeting,
(select count(*) from booking where IsMeeting<>1 and ID={0}) as NonMeeting
from booking
group by year(Date)
order by year(Date) desc
```

but I know this is not correct sql.

Comment: What database? Add appropriate tag. Show sample data and desired output as text tables.

Comment: Recommend not use reserved words as names for anything. Date and Year are both probably intrinsic functions and therefore reserved words.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking something like this....

```
SELECT 
  YEAR(DateField) [Year]
  , COUNT(Id) Total
  , SUM(CASE WHEN ISNULL(IsMeeting,0) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Meeting
  , SUM(CASE WHEN ISNULL(IsMeeting,0) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) NonMeeting
FROM booking
WHERE Id = @anID
GROUP BY YEAR(DateField)
```